# O Box e o fieldset não se ajustam a tela

Tags: html, css

```css
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255,203,219), rgb(217,134,149));
}
.box{
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 30%;
        color: white;

}
 fieldset{
     border: 3px solid rgb(230, 39, 74);
 }
 legend{
     border: 1px solid rgb(230, 39, 74);
     padding: 10px;
     text-align: center;
     background-color: rgb(230, 39, 74);
     border-radius: 8px;
 }
 .inputBox{
    position: relative;
 }
 .inputUser{
     background: none;
     border: none;
     border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
 }
 .labelInput{
     position:absolute;
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     pointer-events: none;
     transition: .5s;
 }
 .inputUser:focus ~ .labelInput,
 .inputUser:valid ~ .labelInput{
    top: -20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: rgb(230, 39, 74);  
 }
 #ano_nascimento{
     border: none;
     padding: 8px;
     border-radius: 10px;
     outline: none;
 }
 #submit{
     background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(228, 77, 122), rgb(243, 41, 78));
     width: 100%;
     border: none;
     padding: 15px;
     color: white;
     font-size: 15px;
     cursor: pointer;
     border-radius: 10px;
    }

    #submit:hover{
     background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(252, 44, 106), rgb(177, 20, 49));
    
    }

    #link{
        padding: 8px;
        color: white;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #link:hover{
        color: black;
       }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">
    <title>Formulario</title>
    <div class="box">
        <form action="">
            <fieldset>
                <legend><b>Formulario</b></legend>
                <br>
                <div class="inputBox">
                    <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" class="inputUser" required>
                    <label for="nome" class="labelInput">Nome completo</label>
                </div>
                <br> 
                <p><b>Sexo</b></p>
                <input type="radio" id="feminino" name="genero" value="feminino" required>
                <label for="feminino">Feminino</label>
                <input type="radio" id="masculino" name="genero" value="masculino" required>
                <label for="masculino">Masculino</label>
                <br><br><br>
                 
                <label for="ano_nascimento"><b>Data de nascimento</b></label>  
                <input type="date" name="ano_nascimento" id="ano_nascimento" required>
                
                <br><br><br>
                <div class="inputBox">
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="inputUser" required>
                    <label for="email" class="labelInput">Email</label>
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <div class="inputBox">
                    <input type="tel" name="tel" id="tel" class="inputUser" required>
                    <label for="tel" class="labelInput">Telefone</label>
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <div class="inputBox">
                    <label for="estado"><b>Estado</b></label>
                    <select id="estado">
                        <option value="AC">Acre</option>
                        <option value="AL">Alagoas</option>
                        <option value="AP">Amapá</option>
                        <option value="AM">Amazonas</option>
                        <option value="BA">Bahia</option>
                        <option value="CE">Ceará</option>
                        <option value="DF">Distrito Federal</option>
                        <option value="ES">Espírito Santo</option>
                        <option value="GO">Goiás</option>
                        <option value="MA">Maranhão</option>
                        <option value="MT">Mato Grosso</option>
                        <option value="MS">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
                        <option value="MG">Minas Gerais</option>
                        <option value="PA">Pará</option>
                        <option value="PB">Paraíba</option>
                        <option value="PR">Paraná</option>
                        <option value="PE">Pernambuco</option>
                        <option value="PI">Piauí</option>
                        <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
                        <option value="RN">Rio Grande do Norte</option>
                        <option value="RS">Rio Grande do Sul</option>
                        <option value="RO">Rondônia</option>
                        <option value="RR">Roraima</option>
                        <option value="SC">Santa Catarina</option>
                        <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
                        <option value="SE">Sergipe</option>
                        <option value="TO">Tocantins</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <div class="inputBox">
                    <label for="cidade"><b>Cidade</b></label>
                    <select id="cidade">
                        <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
                        <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <div class="inputBox">
                    <input type="text" name="cep" id="cep" class="inputUser" required>
                    <label for="cep" class="labelInput">CEP</label>
                </div>            
                <br><br>
                <a href="login.html" id="link">Já tenho acesso</a>
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Enviar" formaction="compra.html">
                
                
            </fieldset>
          
          
        
        </form>
    </div>
    </head>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Poderia por favor [edit] a pergunta e explicar de forma detalhada qual o seu problema. Veja [ask] e faça o nosso [tour].

Answer (score -3):

Então pelo que eu entendi, você gostaria de deixar o "box" e o filedset responsivos.
Nesses casos sempre é interessante usar flexbox, pois facilita bastante a nossa vida, e também evitar ao máximo usar tamanhos fixos(px,em,pc etc )
Mas no seu caso podemos usar uma solução mais simples:

No ".box" nos retiramos essas propriedades:

```
  position:absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   with: 30%;
```

Depois definimos essas:

```
max-width: 400px;
margin: auto;
```

Dessa forma o box já ficará bem mais resposnsivo, e o fildset vai acompanhar.

No final o código ficará dessa forma.

```css
body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(255,203,219), rgb(217,134,149));
}

.box{
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    
    color: white;
}

 fieldset{
     border: 3px solid rgb(230, 39, 74);
   
 }
 legend{
     border: 1px solid rgb(230, 39, 74);
     padding: 10px;
     text-align: center;
     background-color: rgb(230, 39, 74);
     border-radius: 8px;
 }
 .inputBox{
    position: relative;
 }
 .inputUser{
     background: none;
     border: none;
     border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
 }
 .labelInput{
     position:absolute;
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     pointer-events: none;
     transition: .5s;
 }
 .inputUser:focus ~ .labelInput,
 .inputUser:valid ~ .labelInput{
    top: -20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: rgb(230, 39, 74);  
 }
 #ano_nascimento{
     border: none;
     padding: 8px;
     border-radius: 10px;
     outline: none;
 }
 #submit{
     background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(228, 77, 122), rgb(243, 41, 78));
     width: 100%;
     border: none;
     padding: 15px;
     color: white;
     font-size: 15px;
     cursor: pointer;
     border-radius: 10px;
    }

    #submit:hover{
     background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(252, 44, 106), rgb(177, 20, 49));
    
    }

    #link{
        padding: 8px;
        color: white;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #link:hover{
        color: black;
       }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">
    <title>Formulario</title>
    <div class="box">
        <form action="">
            <fieldset>
                <legend><b>Formulario</b></legend>
                <br>
                <div class="inputBox">
                    <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" class="inputUser" required>
                    <label for="nome" class="labelInput">Nome completo</label>
                </div>
                <br> 
                <p><b>Sexo</b></p>
                <input type="radio" id="feminino" name="genero" value="feminino" required>
                <label for="feminino">Feminino</label>
                <input type="radio" id="masculino" name="genero" value="masculino" required>
                <label for="masculino">Masculino</label>
                <br><br><br>
                 
                <label for="ano_nascimento"><b>Data de nascimento</b></label>  
                <input type="date" name="ano_nascimento" id="ano_nascimento" class ="inputs-responsivos" required>
                
                <br><br><br>
                <div class="inputBox">
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="inputUser" required>
                    <label for="email" class="labelInput">Email</label>
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <div class="inputBox">
                    <input type="tel" name="tel" id="tel" class="inputUser" required>
                    <label for="tel" class="labelInput">Telefone</label>
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <div class="inputBox">
                    <label for="estado"><b>Estado</b></label>
                    <select id="estado">
                        <option value="AC">Acre</option>
                        <option value="AL">Alagoas</option>
                        <option value="AP">Amapá</option>
                        <option value="AM">Amazonas</option>
                        <option value="BA">Bahia</option>
                        <option value="CE">Ceará</option>
                        <option value="DF">Distrito Federal</option>
                        <option value="ES">Espírito Santo</option>
                        <option value="GO">Goiás</option>
                        <option value="MA">Maranhão</option>
                        <option value="MT">Mato Grosso</option>
                        <option value="MS">Mato Grosso do Sul</option>
                        <option value="MG">Minas Gerais</option>
                        <option value="PA">Pará</option>
                        <option value="PB">Paraíba</option>
                        <option value="PR">Paraná</option>
                        <option value="PE">Pernambuco</option>
                        <option value="PI">Piauí</option>
                        <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
                        <option value="RN">Rio Grande do Norte</option>
                        <option value="RS">Rio Grande do Sul</option>
                        <option value="RO">Rondônia</option>
                        <option value="RR">Roraima</option>
                        <option value="SC">Santa Catarina</option>
                        <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
                        <option value="SE">Sergipe</option>
                        <option value="TO">Tocantins</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <div class="inputBox">
                    <label for="cidade" ><b>Cidade</b></label>
                    <select id="cidade" >
                        <option value="SP">São Paulo</option>
                        <option value="RJ">Rio de Janeiro</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br><br>
                <div class="inputBox">
                    <input type="text" name="cep" id="cep" class="inputUser" required>
                    <label for="cep" class="labelInput">CEP</label>
                </div>            
                <br><br>
                <a href="login.html" id="link">Já tenho acesso</a>
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Enviar" formaction="compra.html">
                
                
            </fieldset>
          
          
        
        </form>
    </div>
    </head>
</body>
</html>
```